# How know inside hook_entity_presave() if it's a create or update?

Tags: hooks, 8

How know inside hook_entity_presave() if the entity is create or update please ?
Thanks.

Note: I want use presave and not update and insert hook.

Answer (score 12):

Like this:

```
if ($node->isNew()) {

}
```

Note that this only works before saving, in insert/update, it will always return TRUE, because the node has already been saved and is no longer new.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, you also could check

```
if (!empty($node->nid)) {

}
```

Comment: No, that is not correct like this. This specific code snippet is always true in 8.x because $node->nid is an object. $node->nid->value or just !$node->id() would work, except in special cases when saving a new node with a predefined ID (e.g. migrations). isNew() also also much more self-speaking than that check.

Answer (score 0):

An updated entity will always contain a copy of the original entity:

```
if (isset($entity->original)) {

}
```